# Google Analytics tracking events causing server problems

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, widget, tracking

I have a widget that loads a iframe of our site, the widget is loaded on over 100 unique websites, the iframe is pointing to a page on our site that hosts the widget it also loads google analytics tracking code and 1-3 events are fired.

My issue is that our server receives super high cpu usage because of the fired events. I tested this by removing the events and the cpu usage goes down to 1-2%. What I don't understand is why the server is impacted at all?

My thoughts are that Javascript is client side, the event fires and a http request is sent to google analytics servers from the client? At least that's what I think is happening. Why would our server be so heavily impacted to the point of 100% cpu usage and crashing for a client side ga event?

Note: The code is loaded asynchronously.

This is the standard tracking code I'm using: analytics.js:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'auto');

ga('send', 'event', 'widget', 'view', 'post',{
    dimension2 : 8,
    dimension3 : 110,
    dimension7 : 1,
    dimension5 : 1,
    dimension6 : 'somee text here'
}
);
```

Plus maybe 2 more events that look like this one.

New Info Edit:

The spike only happens after the widget is fully loaded and all the javascript is generated. This is the case because the widget has events that fire on click.  The cpu usage is stable for loading the boiler plate ga code. But when the event is fired on click our server spikes.

Comment: You are right, GA is eval'd clientside. At face value, your CPU usage should not be impacted at all by this. Or at least, not signicantly.. whatever the difference between outputting a few extra lines of text calls for.. So this can't be directly related to your CPU usage.  Are the events being output as separate iframes, one for each event? I can see how that would more significantly impact CPU usage, since that's a request to your server for each iframe content being output.

Comment: also, where are those ga values coming from, e.g. where is `dimension2` getting that value of `8` from?  Is there server-side logic dynamically outputting it (and the other values)? are there database queries involved in getting those values? because all of that would also significantly impact server cpu usage

Comment: Yes they are but its minimal, i will double check everything and get back to you. Might be an infinite loop somewhere. Im not getting any log errors..

Comment: okay well i have no idea how things look on your backend but random example.. you have 5 dimensions listed in your post above. Let's say you make a database query for each one of those values. Now multiply by 100  cuz you have 100 sites, that's 500 db queries. Now you factor in how many times those iframe requests are made at a given time: 1000 visitors on a page at a given time? well now you've got 50,000 db queries happening at a given time.  now assume each ga event has same dims and queries, so multiple by another 3.  And this could be way the hell higher depending on how much activity

Comment: those sites get.  Or it could be lower, depending on what you are actually doing on your backend.. e.g. maybe you only have a single db query for all the dims

Comment: in any case, my overall point is it's definitely not the ga code itself causing the jump in your server's cpu, but it definitely sounds like there is something amiss with whatever server-side code you have behind outputting those values

Comment: You would be right but i left all the db  querys that are associated with the widget untouched. i simply commented out the rendering of the ga code. All that code does is some string concatenation.

Comment: Did you comment it out server side or client side?

Comment: Okay well I obviously can't point at a smoking gun since I don't have access to any of this but you know as well as I that the ga code is just arbitrary text the server is outputting, so there's simply no way that the ga code can affect your server's CPU. It *must* be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems i resolved the problem in 2 ways.

The first is before an event fires you must ALWAYS run:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This error was found as a red warning in my google analytics dashboard.

The second is google analytics expects only string for events so the new event code should look like this.

```
//All numbers replaced with strings
ga('send', 'event', 'widget', 'view', 'post',{
    'dimension2' : '8',
    'dimension3' : '110',
    'dimension7' : '1',
    'dimension5' : '1',
    'dimension6' : 'somee text here'
});
```

This error was discovered in my client side console using analytics_debug.js instead of analytics.js when loading boiler plate ga code.

But i still have no idea why my server was so heavily impacted my this. It could be that i accidentally fixed a back end bug while making these changes...